# Python HTTPSConnection encryption and Name or service not found error

Tags: python, encode, httpconnection, get-request

I’m trying to connect to the OPS API but get an error when trying to connect to the url. I get the access_token just fine as detailed in the [documentation](http://documents.epo.org/projects/babylon/eponet.nsf/0/F3ECDCC915C9BCD8C1258060003AA712/$File/ops_v3.2_documentation_-_version_1.3.6_en.pdf) (page 34), but when I try to connect to the url I’m interested in, I get a ‘Name or Service not found’ error.

The documentation states (page 35) that the client should access the OPS resource over an encrypted HTTPS connection, which I think might be the missing step in my code creating this error (or not).

Below is the code I use (replacing #### with my access_token):

```
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
c = HTTPSConnection('ops.epo.org/3.2/rest-services/published-data/search?q=Automation', port=443)
headers2 = {'Authorization': ‘Bearer ########kv5’}
c.request('GET', '/', headers=headers2)
res = c.getresponse()
data = res.read()
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this issue was happening earlier, but it seems to be fine now when I run the following code:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % token }
query = requests.get('http://ops.epo.org/3.2/rest-services/published-data/search?q=Automation', headers=headers)
query.content
```

I get a status response code of 200, and I can parse the content just fine.